# Gravity Forms "save_field_value"

Tags: forms, gravity

I would like multiple fields to be changed after the form has been sent. I found this function on their support page:

```
<?php
add_filter("gform_save_field_value", "save_field_value", 10, 4);
function save_field_value($value, $lead, $field, $form){
        if(absint($form["id"]) <> 94)
                return $value;

        $encode_fields = array(1,2,3);

        if(in_array($field["id"],$encode_fields))
                return base64_encode($value);
        else
                return $value;
}
?>
```

Now assume that I want field ID 1, 2 and 3 to be changed to a value $value1, $value2, $value3 respectively. How do I do this? I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
<?php
add_filter("gform_save_field_value", "save_field_value", 10, 4);
function save_field_value($value, $lead, $field, $form){
        if(absint($form["id"]) <> 94)
                return $value;

        $encode_fields = array(1,2,3);

        if(in_array($field["id"],$encode_fields))
                return array($value1, $value2, $value3);
        else
                return $value;
}
?>
```

Hope someone can help, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
<?php
add_filter("gform_save_field_value", "save_field_value", 10, 4);
function save_field_value($value, $lead, $field, $form){

    if( absint( $form['id'] ) != 94 ) {
            return $value;
    }

    switch( $field['id'] ) {

        // if field ID is "1", return $value1
        case '1':
            return $value1;
            break;

        // if field ID is "2", return $value2
        case '2':
            return $value2;
            break;

        // if field ID is "3", return $value3
        case '2':
            return $value3;
            break;

    }

    return $value;
}
```

This assumes that you are actually setting values for the three $value variables or returning static values in place of these variables.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try that later today! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work... For some reason only $value1 is returned :/

Comment: Can you share what the code currently looks like on your end?

Comment: I basically just used your code. I think, when you return a value, the function stops? So only the first one gets returned. I read somewhere that returning multiple values is not possible :/